# User / membership Plugin

Tags: plugins, users, user-roles, user-registration, membership

I would like to know if there is any plugin that can do the following:

1) Every registered user will have a personal agent assigned. The user can contact via messages only with the assigned agent.

2) Every agent (there will be 4-5 agents in total) can see only the users assigned to him by the administrator.

3) The administrator can see all the users (including the agents).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know a plugin like this. But, my personal solution for this project would be like this :

- create a custom post type for agents
- create users role for agents (and users if you want)
- attach a custom field to users to store the assigned agent (maybe with Advanced custom fields plugin)

Create a page to show the chat or whatever. You need to add some specific code to query the data from custom post types from database.

Something like this.

Do you need more infos?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

More info would be perfect

Comment: I can recommend you to read :

Infos on Custom Post Types
https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Getting started with ACF
https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/

I don't know how you can implement the chat feature for the moment.